# Optimization of "static" loops

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic, compiler-construction, theory

I'm writing a compiled language for fun, and I've recently gotten on a kick for making my optimizing compiler very robust. I've figured out several ways to optimize some things, for instance, 2 + 2 is always 4, so we can do that math at compile time, if(false){ ... } can be removed entirely, etc, but now I've gotten to loops. After some research, I think that what I'm trying to do isn't exactly loop unrolling, but it is still an optimization technique. Let me explain.

Take the following code.

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    s += "x";
}
output(s);
```

As a human, I can sit here and tell you that this is 100% of the time going to be equivalent to

```
output("xxxxx");
```

So, in other words, this loop can be "compiled out" entirely. It's not loop unrolling, but what I'm calling "fully static", that is, there are no inputs that would change the behavior of the segment. My idea is that anything that is fully static can be resolved to a single value, anything that relies on input or makes conditional output of course can't be optimized further. So, from the machine's point of view, what do I need to consider? What makes a loop "fully static?"

I've come up with three types of loops that I need to figure out how to categorize. Loops that will always end up with the same machine state after every run, regardless of inputs, loops that WILL NEVER complete, and loops that I can't figure out one way or the other. In the case that I can't figure it out (it conditionally changes how many times it will run based on dynamic inputs), I'm not worried about optimizing. Loops that are infinite will be a compile error/warning unless specifically suppressed by the programmer, and loops that are the same every time should just skip directly to putting the machine in the proper state, without looping.

The main case of course to optimize is the static loop iterations, when all the function calls inside are also static. Determining if a loop has dynamic components is easy enough, and if it's not dynamic, I guess it has to be static. The thing I can't figure out is how to detect if it's going to be infinite or not. Does anyone have any thoughts on this? I know this is a subset of the halting problem, but I feel it's solvable; the halting problem is a problem due to the fact that for some subsets of programs, you just can't tell it may run forever, it may not, but I don't want to consider those cases, I just want to consider the cases where it WILL halt, or it WILL NOT halt, but first I have to distinguish between the three states.

Comment: To get an idea of what's actually supported along this line at the present time, you might want to read about the limitations on `constexpr` in the new C++ standard.

Comment: If you can statically determine that the loop condition is always true, and there is no other way to exit the loop, then you know the loop won't terminate.

Comment: In your example, you don't necessarily know that String s is not also modified by another file referencing it via extern and modifying it in a parallel thread.

Comment: @JerryCoffin from wikipedia: "the function body cannot declare variables". That rules out most loops then. I wonder if that's due to a theoretical limit or a practical one. I feel like there's again, a subset of problems that can still be programmatically detected and solved, so should be.

Comment: @TJD: Er, yes I do. I'm writing the language. ;)

Comment: @wraithguard01, so your language doesn't support multiple source files?

Comment: @VaughnCato Hmm. How does one do that? for(int i = 0; i < 5; i--){} is infinite, obviously, but what are we doing in our head to know that? What about for(int i = 0; i < 5; i--){ if(i%2==0){ i+=2; }} is not infinite, though it looks like it would be at first.

Comment: @TJD: It does, but there's no way for another thread or source to get a reference to s, at least at that point in the code.

Comment: @wraithguard01: The limitations they decided on are based on both theoretical and practical limits, though I'm not sure there's a lot of documentation about exactly which was which. You can undoubtedly do  more (especially if the rest of your language is simpler), but exactly how much I'm not sure.

Comment: It would be neat if static loops could be used like a preprocessor mechanism, then send generated code to an eval function; as long as the compiler knew it could be statically resolved, including the eval(), then hey, why not?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i--){}` doesn't look very infinite to me, unless you have weird ints that don't wrap. Anyway, it's easy enough to detect the "simple cases", so how far do you want to go with that?

Comment: @wraithguard01 Fun fact: Your loop you claim to be infinite, clearly is not (i goes `0,1,0,1` for ever) while the first one will usually end when the int wraps around ;)

Comment: Oh, oops. Well, you get my point, right? haha. @harold: The idea is that anything that can be detected should. In other words, C++'s constexpr should be able to happen automatically, based on certain rules.

Comment: That's not even a solved problem you know, it's only known that *not all* cases can be detected, not how many *can* be. C++'s constexpr doesn't allow everything either, in fact it is so restrictive that for your examples it would be completely useless - it can only handle recursion (no loops).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a kind of a symbolic solver that can be defined for several classes, but not generally.

Let's restrict the requirements a bit: no number overflow, just for loops (while can be sometimes transformed to full for loop, except when using continue etc.), no breaks, no modifications of the control variable inside the for loop.

`for (var i = S; E(i); i = U(i))` ...

where E(i) and U(i) are expressions that can be symbolically manipulated. There are several classes that are relatively easy:

`U(i) = i + CONSTANT` : `n`-th cycle the value of `i` is `S + n * CONSTANT`

`U(i) = i * CONSTANT` : `n`-th cycle the value of `i` is `S * CONSTANT^n`

`U(i) = i / CONSTANT` : `n`-th cycle the value of `i` is `S * CONSTANT^-n`

`U(i) = (i + CONSTANT) % M` : `n`-th cycle the value of `i` is `(S + n * CONSTANT) % M`

and some other quite easy combinations (and some very difficult ones)

Determining whether the loop terminates is searching for `n` where `E(i(n))` is false.
This can be done by some symbolic manipulation for a lot of cases, but there is a lot of work involved in making the solver.

E.g.

- `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`,
- `i(n) = 0 + n * 1 = n`, `E(i(n))` => `not(n < 5)` =>
- `n >= 5` => stops for `n = 5`

---

- `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i--)`,
- `i(n) = 0 + n * -1 = -n`, `E(i(n))` => `not(-n < 5)` => `-n >= 5` =>
- `n < -5` - since `n` is a non-negative whole number this is never true - never stops

---

- `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i = (i + 1) % 3)`,
- `E(i(n))` => `not(n % 3 < 5)` => `n % 3 >= 5` => this is never true => never stops

---

- `for(int i = 10; i + 10 < 500; i = i + 2 * i)` =>
- `for(int i = 10; i < 480; i = 3 * i)`,
- `i(n) = 10 * 3^n`,
- `E(i(n))` => `not(10 * 3^n < 480)` => `10 * 3^n >= 480` => `3^n >= 48` => `n >= log3(48)` => `n >= 3.5...` =>
- since n is whole => it will stop for `n = 4`

for other cases it would be good if they can get transformed to the ones you can already solve...

Many tricks for symbolic manipulation come from Lisp era, and are not too difficult. Although the ones described (or variants) are the most common types practice, there are many more difficult and/or impossible to solve scenarios.

Comment: What usually screws this up is indirect addressing (or indexing into arrays which is equivalent) causing possible aliasing between values.  Where you don't if aliasing occurs or not, you can't apply your algebraic laws.   So you need really good flow analysis and alias resolution to optimize loops, unless they operate on "whole" values like OP's example.

Comment: yes, it should have been mentioned earlier that this is certainly true for most of the languages we use now. However, since this is for a new language that @wraithguard01 is making, there is an open field for some design compromises and restrictions, although I am not sure what those can be now.

Comment: If you have mutable arrays and indexes you've got aliasing troubles (think of array base + index as a pointer and should be obvious).

Comment: So, it appears as though all the cases you have listed here are convertable to a (python) for + range (for i in range(10)) construct. I can easily see how to optimize that, I wonder if that's the key here? If it can be converted to a foreach (or is already a foreach with static inputs), it can always be optimized out.